# How to filter array of NSDictionary for key separated by comma

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an array of NSDictionary.NSDictionary has a key named as multiple_image key that contain string separated by ,.

I want set of array that contain 123.png for multiple_images key.
Can some one show me how to do this using NSPredicate or without predicate.

```
//Array 
{
    Image = "<UIImage: 0xf72df30>";
    active = yes;
    "admin_id" = 169;
    "category_id" = 32;
    "chef_id" = 175;
    descr = "Cool tea to cool down the mind.";
    id = 110;
    "multiple_images" = "Jellyfish.jpg,345.png";
    name = "Southern Sweet Ice Tea";
    price = 160;
    rating = 3;
    selected = 0;
    "subcat_id" = 23;
    "tag_id" = 45;
    "tax_id" = 10;
    "tax_value" = "12.00";
},
    {
    Image = "<UIImage: 0xf72ebd0>";
    active = yes;
    "admin_id" = 169;
    "category_id" = 31;
    "chef_id" = 175;
    descr = "Ingredients are almonds or cashews. No hydrogenated stuff, no extra weirdo ingredients";
    id = 107;
    "multiple_images" = "Jellyfish.jpg,123.png";
    name = "Butter Chicken";
    price = 300;
    rating = 3;
    selected = 0;
    "subcat_id" = 24;
    "tag_id" = 43;
    "tax_id" = 9;
    "tax_value" = "0.00";
},
    {
    Image = "<UIImage: 0xf72f870>";
    active = yes;
    "admin_id" = 169;
    "category_id" = 31;
    "chef_id" = 173;
    descr = "Raw vegetables  including carrots, cucumbers.";
    id = 100;
    "multiple_images" = "Jellyfish.jpg,shake.png,";
    name = Salads;
    price = 50;
    rating = 3;
    selected = 0;
    "subcat_id" = 22;
    "tag_id" = 44;
    "tax_id" = 9;
    "tax_value" = "0.00";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using predicates,

```
[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"multiple_images CONTAINS '123'"]];
```

Using predicates, but with blocks

```
    NSArray *filtered = [test filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:
    ^BOOL(NSDictionary *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary * bindings) {
        NSString *key = @"123";
        return ([evaluatedObject[@"multiple_images"] rangeOfString:key].location != NSNotFound);
    }]];
```

Comment: what if i want to  split dictionary into two part one contain 123.png while  another Jellyfish.jpg.

Comment: Can you guarantee that no item in array has both 123 and Jellyfish? In that case just run two filters one on 123 one on the other.

Comment: @SurajGupta The way you are handling the multiple images is wrong. You should have an array of strings, not a single string seperated by commas. If you say your exact use case it would be easy to remove guess work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NSDictionary *item = mainArray[0];

NSString *imagesString = item[@"multiple_images"];

NSArray *images = [imagesString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Now you can use the images

Comment: I dont want images,i need a set of array that contain 123.png

Comment: @SurajGupta Do you want to find the item which has `123.png` in it's multiple_images. Can you clarify.

Comment: I need    {
    Image = "<UIImage: 0xf72ebd0>";
    active = yes;
    "admin_id" = 169;
    "category_id" = 31;
    "chef_id" = 175;
    descr = "Ingredients are almonds or cashews. No hydrogenated stuff, no extra weirdo ingredients";
    id = 107;
    "multiple_images" = "123.png";
    name = "Butter Chicken";
    price = 300;
    rating = 3;
    selected = 0;
    "subcat_id" = 24;
    "tag_id" = 43;
    "tax_id" = 9;
    "tax_value" = "0.00";
}

Comment: @SurajGupta The answer by Dmitry Shevchenko exactly does that rite.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
     for (int i=0; i<[mainArray count]; i++) {
            NSDictionary *item = [mainArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *imagesString = item[@"multiple_images"];
            NSArray *images = [imagesString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

            for (int j=0;j<[images count]; j++) {
                if ([[images objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"123.png"]) {
                    ///Your Required code;
                }
            }
      }
```

Comment: I dont wat to use looping etc.

Comment: @SurajGupta sorry sir, in your question you not specify you don't want to use looping...

Answer (score 0):

So you want to save the dictionary that has 123.png.

maybe you can try something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray new];// your array of objects(dictionaries)
__block NSMutableArray *images123 = [NSMutableArray new];
[arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = (NSMutableDictionary *)obj;

    if([[dictionary allKeys]containsObject:@"multiple_images"]){
        NSString *imageList = (NSString *)[dictionary objectForKey:@"multiple_images"];
        NSArray *arrayImages = [imageList componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        if([arrayImages containsObject:@"123.png"]){
            [images123 addObject:dictionary];
        }
    }
}];
```